# Why is my cable net not working on Windows? Unidentified Network

Tags: windows, networking

My Wifi works fine,and on the router all 4 LANS are blinking.But I can not use cable
Settings
[image]
[image]
Properties

```
Link speed (Receive/Transmit):  1000/1000 (Mbps)
Link-local IPv6 address:    fe80::f074:43aa:p13e:3e61%7
IPv6 DNS servers:   fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
IPv4 address:   192.168.137.1
Manufacturer:   Intel Corporation
Description:    Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
Driver version: 12.17.10.8
Physical address (MAC): 9C-8E-91-3E-1A-4F
```

This is the ipconfig output

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20cc:eb26:39cc:1eb9%50
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.112.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f079:43aa:e15e:3e61%7
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I need to enable this access now. How to fix this networking problem?

Comment: Make sure you have a good Ethernet wire between Computer and Router. Then turn off Wireless. Ethernet should connect. Check this.

Comment: @John I checked everything, ethernet is not connected.

Comment: You may need to try a USB - LAN adapter in place of the built in Ethernet.

Comment: @John Please,take a look at my edit. How to change adapter?

Comment: I do not understand the "cable" part. The connection should be Ethernet.  Make sure this is plugged into a port on the wireless router. If your box is modem/router/wireless, then a port on that should work but you may wish to contact your ISP.